# Django Unittest how to adjust client.post to set data in request.META

Tags: django, unit-testing, post, client

I am trying to test a view by posting data to the view, but the view uses a key/value from request.META.   How do I adjust my client.post to ensure the request.META data is populated ?

The following example isn't working!

Example from unittest:

```
        with mock.patch("......") as gt:
            header = {'SOME_SIGNATURE': 'BLAH'}
            gt.side_effect = ValueError
            response = self.client.post('/webhook/', data={'input': 'hi'}, 
                                    content_type='application/json', follow=False,
                                    secure=False, extra=header)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 400)
```

Code from the view:

```
def my_webhook_view(request):

  # Extract Data from Webhook
  payload = request.body

  # THIS LINE CAUSES MY UNITTESTS TO FAIL
  sig_header = request.META['HTTP_SOME_SIGNATURE']
  
  ......
```

Answer (score 3):

`extra` is not a separate argument to the `post` method, but rather an catch-all keyword arguments variable. To pass your headers, simply use:

```
        response = self.client.post('/webhook/', data={'input': 'hi'}, 
                                content_type='application/json', follow=False,
                                secure=False, **header)
```

Also, make sure to include a `HTTP_` prefix in your headers list.

Comment: Thanks for the help.